# How can I solve the errors in apt update in raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt-get, apt

Recently I edit my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change jessie to stretch to get the new version of gcc-6. However I when I change `stretch` back to `jessie`, and run `sudo apt-get update` I got a lot of errors. How can I solve it.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy InRelease                             
Get:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie InRelease [14.9 kB]            
Err:1 http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy InRelease                                 
  The following signatures were invalid: FF9FD9E73808E2376CB76F0AED4BF9140C50B1C5
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian jessie InRelease
Get:5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/main armhf Packages [9534 kB]
Hit:3 https://packagecloud.io/Hypriot/Schatzkiste/raspbian jessie InRelease
Get:6 http://124.202.164.8/files/311600000A34E137/http.debian.net/debian jessie/main armhf Packages [169 kB]         
Err:6 http://124.202.164.8/files/311600000A34E137/http.debian.net/debian jessie/main armhf Packages
  Writing more data than expected (196868 > 169365)
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:169365 [weak]
   - SHA256:779179f25b91efa4fdbf69aeb7c37d444e104e3b8d359daf27bc4db4d330003f
   - SHA1:aa605ce914ddacfd4b8c71c72bab3a95b76c0ed5 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f0867f34045767904d0caa686f288615 [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 15:58:01 +0000
Get:7 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie InRelease [14.9 kB]                                                                                                                         
Get:8 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/rpi Sources [1132 B]                                                                                                                        
Get:9 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/non-free Sources [113 kB]                                                                                                                   
Get:10 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/main Sources [7754 kB]                                                                                                                     
Ign:11 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo raspbian-jessie InRelease                                                                                                                           
Get:12 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/contrib armhf Packages [43.3 kB]                                                                                                    
Get:13 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/non-free armhf Packages [84.2 kB]                                                                                                   
Get:14 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/rpi armhf Packages [1356 B]                                                                                                         
Err:15 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo raspbian-jessie Release                                                                                                                             
  gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Get:16 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie/contrib Sources [64.5 kB]                                                                                                                  
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                 
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: FF9FD9E73808E2376CB76F0AED4BF9140C50B1C5
E: The repository 'https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo raspbian-jessie Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My sources.list file

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
 deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and below solution worked for me.

Create a file called badproxy with below lines:

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;
```

then copy the file into the apt config folder:

cp ./badproxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy

I tried above suggestion from [docker form](https://forums.docker.com/t/hash-sum-mismatch-writing-more-data-as-expected/45940/2)

Comment: I tried it behind a proxy and firewall.  This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score -5):

```
sudo apt remove gnupg
sudo apt install --reinstall gnupg2 (possibly not necessary, but doesn't hurt)
sudo apt install dirmngr
```

Then run

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key FF9FD9E73808E2376CB76F0AED4BF9140C50B1C5
gpg -a --export  FF9FD9E73808E2376CB76F0AED4BF9140C50B1C5 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: following the first instruction (sudo apt remove gnupg) uninstalled "apt", not a good thing..!